# Installing bootstrap with npm is throwing errors

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am basically trying to install bootstrap (sass version) with npm and I have done so by following this guide here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/ (see the npm part).

then I continued setting it up by following this guide here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/ so that I could compile the sass into css.

The issue is that when I am running the command npm run dist I get the below error:

[image]
I can't figure out such error and have also tried researching the web for a similar error but could not find anything. I can't understand why such a popular framework is so frustrating to get up and running.

Any insights please?

**Update**:

Here is the [debug.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13CbUeQwwkTbB4S3tprSIgR3jndfJcpll)

Comment: did you check the debug.log? post it here as well

Comment: @HendrikEng I have now attached the debug.log with my question, please see under Update heading. I have checked it but did not understand much to be honest. Thanks for your help.